# How to find combobox and set value using Selenium and find_element_by_xpath

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set a value in a combobox using selenium. But the find_element_by_xpath statement fails to find the combobox by class or ng-model
(in detail I'm trying to change the timeperiod for a stock from one day to one week)

The web page contains the following javascript for the element I'm searching for

```
**<select ng-model="analysisGraph.periodselector.period" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse user-success ng-touched">**
    <!-- ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.dayOnly -->
    <option ng-if="!analysisGraph.periodselector.dayOnly" value="INTRADAY" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Intradag</option><!-- end ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.dayOnly --><!-- ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.dayOnly -->
    <option ng-if="!analysisGraph.periodselector.dayOnly" value="ONE_WEEK" class="ng-binding ng-scope">1 uke</option><!-- end ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.dayOnly -->
        <option value="ONE_MONTH" class="ng-binding">1 mnd</option><!-- ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide3m -->
    <option ng-if="!analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide3m" value="THREE_MONTHS" class="ng-binding ng-scope">3 mnd</option><!-- end ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide3m --><!-- ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide6m -->
    <option ng-if="!analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide6m" value="SIX_MONTHS" class="ng-binding ng-scope">6 mnd</option><!-- end ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide6m -->
        <option value="YTD" class="ng-binding">YTD</option><!-- ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide1y -->
    <option ng-if="!analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide1y" value="ONE_YEAR" class="ng-binding ng-scope">1 år</option><!-- end ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide1y --><!-- ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide3y -->
    <option ng-if="!analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide3y" value="THREE_YEARS" class="ng-binding ng-scope">3 år</option><!-- end ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide3y --><!-- ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide5y -->
    <option ng-if="!analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide5y" value="FIVE_YEARS" class="ng-binding ng-scope">5 år</option><!-- end ngIf: !analysisGraph.periodselector.hideOption.hide5y --><!-- ngIf: hasLaunchData -->
</select>
```

I have tried the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql
import ose_data

chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.oslobors.no/markedsaktivitet/#/details/ADE.OSE/overview')
time.sleep(5)
bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
**driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse user-success ng-touched']/option[text()='ONE_WEEK']").click()**
```

but it fails with the following error:

*Error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@class='ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse user-success ng-touched']/option[text()='ONE_WEEK']"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)*

I also tried searching with
**driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model='analysisGraph.periodselector.period']/option[text()='ONE_WEEK']").click()**

With the same error, anyone see any obious errors from a noob Python programer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath is wrong, use `select[ng-model="analysisGraph.periodselector.period"]` css selector to get the element. The element is a drop-down with [select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), to select it use `Select` class.  Added `WebDriverWait` to wait for element to be clickable before interact with it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql
import ose_data
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.oslobors.no/markedsaktivitet/#/details/ADE.OSE/overview')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
details_period = Select(wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select[ng-model="analysisGraph.periodselector.period"]'))))
details_period.select_by_value('ONE_WEEK')

# You can also use
# details_period.select_by_visible_text()
# details_period.select_by_index()
```